# How to secure GET request when queried in a browser tab

Tags: http, go

I am currently assigned in developing stock market data API with security in top of all. I was able to secure incoming GET requests using JWT, API keys,middleware auths.

Let's say when the user is not logged in, as we all know, all http methods esp GET are responding with http status 401 unauthorized access.

My problem is when the user is logged in in our app, the API requests can be now queried successfully (server to server) but **when I copy the request link to the browser new tab (say chrome), I can see the reply**. It is expected since the user is logged in but I want that the request response will not be seen in the browser. Other competitors of ours use POST to counter the browser GET default.

Should we move to POST? Im struggling since GET is the proper http method for requesting stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For private stuff like stock market data, My first choice would have been a post request.

I had once blocked GET API request from browsers by detecting a browser, based on stuff like  having a useragent string, and custom head metadata, but based on experience, it isn't a perfect solution.

Another trick I had used in past was using a simple encryption algorithm,(it wasn't secure but was fast. It was merely a distraction ) to encrypt values. So if someone did extract the json response, the data would be garbage, unless decrypted with key, which could be jwt token in your case.

Again, These tricks will do nothing for security against highly technical person, but will be enough of a distraction to regular to average reverse engg tricks. Also disclaimer, I never used GET for anything important as financial and stocks related information. My rule was GET for normal filler stuff, and POST for important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to move to `POST` if you want to hide the output in the browser window. As with `GET`, the browser will always show the output directly.

However, please note that if anyone want to see the API response, they can still simulate the API calls using JS and see the response in their browser console, or use a client like Postman to get the response. If they have proper tokens, they can always inspect your response, there's no way around it.

I believe it's working in the new tab as well because the user is logged in and the JWT token is stored in cookie / localstorage / in a way that is accessible from new tabs. And your server is also being able to access that.

If you send the token using a JS application (React may be?) and tweak your server to accept the token through a request header every time, in that case, just opening that url will no longer work because it will have the token missing in request header.

Comment: In terms of accessing the API response using postman, I configured it with a server to server authentication, thus rest-clients cant access it even requests that are programmed (bot requests). For your last suggestion, if you are in your browser with successful login status, you can still get response because it is a GET method and in this case, authorized since user is logged in.

Comment: If the token is sent over in the request header, that should require the browser to manually put that in the header since the browser wouldn't know to do that itself. For the server to server communication part, that would also mean any other clients can't access the API from a browser or a mobile device directly. They have to be proxied via another server. And if the user authenticates with that proxy server, it will still happen.

Comment: yes the token is sent over the request header but the request is sent via server-to-server communication.